# Make more than one request by HttpWebRequest to Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Friends,i want to scrape a third party web pages and get information from there by `httpwebrequest` c#.net. I made a simple application in asp.net,c#. and hosted in webserver IIS 7 that enable user to scrape web page easily.

It is working fine by single user. but problem is that when more than one user is requesting at the same time then server block the request.  the server allow max 2 concurrent request

My application is running on IIS7, asp.net 4.0.

any help please

Comment: is it not more correct to give the end user to give a link to the site you are scraping. I can understand if you are doing data mining, but this is daylight robbery to host someonelse's content in your application

Answer (score 0):

If the limit is managed by the remote server then there's probably not much you can do. It's there to prevent spamming and that's what it's doing.

It does sound like you're just hitting the default connection limit for your own machine though. Have a look at the [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Use it like this:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
```

Some reading on it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit.aspx).

Comment: but it doesn't work. it show messge as Due to technical reasons, you are unable to access the system. Please try after some time.
Code : 10001

Source IP xx.xx.xx.xx  . when i type url then also show this error

Comment: Then the block is at the server end and there's nothing you can do about it. It's designed to stop you doing what you want to do, and it's working. Sorry.